# How to identify changed row in editable grid in LightSwitch (C#)

Tags: grid, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an editable grid for invoices and a few checkbox columns like invoice, sent to customer / ok to invoice. I have fields updated by/updated on for these boolean fields.

I want to update these two columns if checkbox values have been changed. I am not sure how can I do this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I do this is by implementing the *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface for the *SelectedItem* property of the DataGrid. Perfect for "*I want to update these two columns if checkbox values have been changed*".

If you need code just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In the screen designer for the page select the property from the query (on the left) that represents the checkbox. Then click the drop down next to the "write code" link and implement the method for xxx_Changed.

Here you can then set values for your other fields based on this input.

Comment: That would work if the controls were just in a screen, but not if the controls are in a data grid.

Comment: This works regardless of whether the property bound to the checkbox is displayed in or outside of a grid. I did double check, but yes, you can use all the functionality out of the Lightswitch box to achieve the desired results.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you, but I just don't see how it can, unless we're actually talking about slightly different things.

Comment: Not at all, perhaps I've misunderstood. I had assumed the checkboxes and audit records are contained within the grid in which case the above works; I have this working in a live deployed application. If they are not all within the grid then I also subscribe to events to manage updates. Anyway, the OP has marked your answer so I'm sure they have the solution they were looking for.